# Custom Listview setonItemClickListner is not working in DialogFragment using Viewbinding in kotlin

Tags: kotlin, listview, android-dialogfragment, baseadapter

Click on TextView open DialogFragment. Custom Listview set in DialogFragment. Listview item set in textview. Data set in Listview but when click listview item is not any response but when we click on listview item text then give error "java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.Integer cannot be cast model.Serve"

MainActivity.kt

```
binding.tvProductServeno.setOnClickListener {
           var dialogC = CustomDialog(serveNo)

            dialogC.show(supportFragmentManager,"customDialog")
 }
```

CustomDialog.kt

```
class CustomDialog(val servList: ArrayList<Serve>) : DialogFragment() {

    private val TAG = "CustomDialog"

    interface OnInputListener {
        fun sendInput(input: String?)
    }

    var mOnInputListener: OnInputListener? = null

    override fun onCreateView(inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?, savedInstanceState: Bundle?): View? {
        val inflater = context?.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE) as LayoutInflater
        val binding = DialogListViewBinding.inflate(inflater)

        val builder = AlertDialog.Builder(requireContext())
        val servAdapter = DialogListAdapter(servList, requireContext())
        binding.listViewDialog.adapter = servAdapter
        servAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged()
        val dialog = builder.create()
        dialog.show()

        binding.listViewDialog.setOnItemClickListener { adapterView, view, i, l ->

            val serve = adapterView.getItemAtPosition(i) as Serve

            val serve1 = serve.serveNo

           /* (activity as AddProduct?)..setText(input)*/
            mOnInputListener?.sendInput(serve1.toString())

            dialog.dismiss()
            Toast.makeText(requireContext(), serve1.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
        }


        return binding.root
    }

    override fun onCreateDialog(savedInstanceState: Bundle?): Dialog {
        return super.onCreateDialog(savedInstanceState)
    }


    override fun onAttach(context: Context) {
        super.onAttach(context)

        try {
            mOnInputListener = activity as OnInputListener?
        } catch (e: ClassCastException) {
            Log.e(TAG, "onAttach: ClassCastException: " + e.message)
        }
    }
}
```

Data Display in Listview. When Click on Listview item then it's not give any response. Listview iten value is not set in textview but click on listview item text is give error ClassCastException.

DialogListAdapter.kt

```
class DialogListAdapter (val servNo : ArrayList<Serve>,val context: Context) : BaseAdapter() {
    override fun getCount(): Int {
        return  servNo.size
    }

    override fun getItem(p0: Int): Any {
        return p0
    }

    override fun getItemId(p0: Int): Long {
        return  p0.toLong()
    }

    override fun getView(p0: Int, p1: View?, p2: ViewGroup?): View {
        val inflater = context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE) as LayoutInflater
        val binding = DialogListItemBinding.inflate(inflater)

        //val serve = getItem(p0) as Serve

        val ser = servNo.get(p0)
        binding.tvListViewDialogItem.text = ser.serveNo

        return binding.root
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to change the `getItem` function in the `DialogListAdapter` to:

```
override fun getItem(p0: Int): Serve = servNo[p0]
```

Comment: ClassCastException error is fix but Listview whole row is not select only item text is select.